# PHP: How can I set a default value for $_POST array?

Tags: php

I'm building an e-commerce webpage and working on the "add to cart" button on the checkout page. Here, when the first page is loaded, I want to show a default value "1". And after that, the customer can adjust the quantity. I'm using the POST method to save the quantity input, but I'm not sure how to set the default value "1". Below is my code:

```
<section>
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST)) {
      $error = false;
      if (empty($_POST["quantityInput"])) {
          echo "<p class='errorMessage'> Quantity must be entered. </p>";
          $error = true;
      }
  }
?>

<td class="quantityColumn">
  <form action="cart.php" method="post">
      <input type="number" id="quantityInput" name="quantityInput" min="1" max="10"
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST["quantityInput"])) echo "value='" . $_POST["quantityInput"] . "'";
      ?>>
      <input type="submit" id="updateButton" value="Update">
  </form>
</td>
</section>
```

I tried setting `$_POST['quantityInput'] = "1"`, but when I enter a new value and submit the form, it only shows "1", and not the new value... Is there a way to set a default value using PHP? What method/function should I look into?

Comment: `if( ){...} else { echo "value='1'; }`

Comment: `$quantityInput = 1; if (isset($_POST["quantityInput"])) $quantityInput = $_POST["quantityInput"] ; ` .  After this just use `$quantityInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [null coalescing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) operator if `quantityInput` is not defined

Eg.

```
$_POST["quantityInput"] = $_POST["quantityInput"] ?? 1;
// Or on the short form
$_POST["quantityInput"] ??= 1;
```

It will set `$_POST["quantityInput"]` to 1 if not exist, by mean default value

Answer (score 0):

The input field can be written like this:

```
 <input
    type="number"
    id="quantityInput"
    name="quantityInput"
    min="1"
    max="10"
    value="<?= isset($_POST["quantityInput"]) ? 1 : $_POST["quantityInput"] ?>"
 >
```

Comment: This code will ignore quantityInput if it's zero, is that intentional?